# WebService Method request in console of debugger disappears while the method is called on client click event of asp:button

Tags: jquery, .net, dom

I do not know how this exactly happened, but please help to boost up my knowledge.

I have an asp button in .ascx as,

```
<asp:Button ID="btnConfirm" runat="server" Text="Purchase" 
            OnClick="btnConfirm_Click" />.
```

I need some jQuery code to run after a client clicks this button. And I have coded
to send clientId of the button to .js file as,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(this).ShopItem({           
        confirmBtnClientID: '<%=btnConfirm.ClientID %>'            
    });
});
```

And in .js file I have full access to the clientId of this button as  "p.confirmBtnClientID".

```
$("#" + p.confirmBtnClientID).live('click', function () {
                ItemControl.ItemPurchase();
            });
```

Method, ItemPurchase calls a method in Webservice and returns void.

```
protected void btnConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 //does stuffs and
 //calls a different method in the same .js file 
}
```

And now my question is that(I am using firefox as browser) :
1. In the console of the debugger my webservice request is suddenly disappeared but I need it to view, How can I?
2. I have a table with id="tblCart" and it was made to hide and no of the method containing

```
     $('#tblCart tr:not(:first)').each(function (index, value) {
                    var $me = $(this);
                    itemID += ($me.attr('id')) + ',';
                    if ($me.find('.itemQty').length > 0) {
                        itemQty += ($me.find('.itemQty').val()) + ',';
                    }
                });
});
```

is called.But only another method is called declaring a global variable in .js file.
I have a problem that after button's click $me.attr('id') is not defined.

I am sorry to have confusion about jQuery global variables (for question 2).
ThankFul for your response.

Answer (score 1):

1) For the 1st part if you're using Firebug , you can view the 'Net' tab for all the XHR requests and if you need them to persist even after redirecting or posting. Select 'persist' button at the left hand side.
2) Ideally the id should have come even if it is hidden ,incase the element is not deleted.

Comment: Thank you, Sir, I am now able to view the XHR request but I was to know why the console cannot keep such request details within it? And for question(2) if the control id should have come, even if its hidden, then why its attr('id') is undefined.

Comment: what does $(this) give in the Console debugger ?

Comment: $(this) gives all the table rows except first. This table is just hidden not removed. And non of the function containing this code is called rather another method of same .js is called using a so called global variable. Problem is continuing till now.

Comment: then i think what you need is $(this)[index] assigned to $me... give it a try